# Is there something I can change to make my view run faster?

Tags: sql, oracle

I just created a view but it is really slow, since my actual table has something around 800k rows.

Is there something I can change in the actual sql code to make it run faster?

Here is how it looks now:

```
Select B.*    
FROM    
    (Select A.*, (select count(B.KEY_ID)/77 
                  FROM book_new B 
                  where B.KEY_ID = A.KEY_ID) as COUNT_KEY

     FROM    
       (select *
        from book_new 
        where region = 'US' 
          and (actual_release_date is null or 
               actual_release_date >= To_Date( '01/07/16','dd/mm/yy'))
       ) A
   ) B

WHERE B.COUNT_KEY = 1 
   OR (B.COUNT_KEY > 1 AND B.NEW_OLD <> 'Old')
```

Comment: Mysql or Oracle? This is tagged as both

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: Also  use meaninful and dont repeat the alias, is easy get confuse between `A` and `B`

Comment: What would help me the most, and perhaps others as well (in addition to what you posted, not instead of it!) would be: table names and column names (only those columns needed to solve the problem), the problem requirement, a small sample of data and sample of desired output. Some of those can be reverse engineered from the query you posted, but that is time-consuming and shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I dont usually do this but since this is a rather simple sql, I just went for A and B.

My Table has 800k rows and and 20 Columns

It has 1 index: KEY_ID

Comment: What is the current execution time?

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious things to do are add indexes:

- Add an index on `book_new(key_id)`
- Add an index on `book_new(region, actual_release_date)`

These are probably sufficient.  It is possible that rewriting the query would help, but this is a good beginning.  If you want to rewrite the query, it would help if you described the logic you are trying to implement.

Comment: The query selects books that that are either unreleased or released in the past year (almost).  Unless they've been in business a long time, the second index you suggest might not be that great.  If they've been in business 10 years, this query might return 10% of the rows, which is often well into the range where a FTS is faster.  All speculation, of course.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this issue based on your needs

- You can create an indexed view
- You can create an index in the base tables which are used in this view.
- You can use the required columns in the SELECT statement instead of using SELECT * FROM,
- If the table contains many columns but you require only few columns, you can create a NON CLUSTERED INDEX with INCLUDE COLUMNS option which will reduce the LOGICAL READS.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, replace the scalar subquery for `COUNT_KEY` with a windowed `COUNT(*)`.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
select book_new.*, COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY book_new.key_id)/77 COUNT_KEY
        from book_new 
        where region = 'US' 
          and (actual_release_date is null or 
               actual_release_date >= To_Date( '01/07/16','dd/mm/yy'))
)
WHERE count_key = 1 OR ( count_key > 1 AND new_old <> 'Old' )
```

This way, you only go through the `BOOK_NEW` table one time.

BTW, I agree with other comments that this query makes little sense.